# What does putting curly brackets around a variale when initializing it does exactly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Example :

```
const {http} = require('http');
```

I have seen something about "destructing" and have read some resources about that, but I am still very confused about what it actually does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It extracts that property from the object.
The meaning of it is exacly the same as writing this:

```
const http = require('http').http;
```

You can read more about object destructuring (and destructuring in general) here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Comment: Ok, thanks! It's much clearer like that!